# errno: 1452, sqlMessage: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I want to add images in the database, there are 2 tables connected to each others (activity and activityImages). I want to add the the activity name and the description to the activity table, and the activityID added automatically, then I want to add the image, and insert the activityID with the image to the activityImages table (the activityID is foreign key).
[image]

When I insert actual value for the activityID, the image added successfully, but When I define a variable to return the value of last ID inserted appear this error:

```
errno: 1452,
  sqlMessage: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (finaldatabase.`activityimages`, CONSTRAINT activityimages_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (ActivityID) REFERENCES activity (ActivityID))',
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO activityimages(ActivityID, image) VALUES ("SELECT ActivityID FROM activity WHERE ActivityID = LAST_INSERT_ID()", "images/05.jpg-1639940921922.jpeg")'
```

This is the code

```
const setdatavalues= (event)=>{
  Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/addevent')
  .then(() => {
      console.log('لقد قمت باختيار صورة')
      setphoto(event.target.files[0])
  })     
}

const AddNewEvent = () => {
  
  if(ActivityName === "" || Description === ""){
      setresponse('يرجى تعبئة الحقول الفارغة');
  } 
  Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/addevent', {
      ActivityName: ActivityName,
      Description: Description,
  }).then(()=>{
      Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/addevent')
      .then((respons) => {
          console.log(respons.data)
          const formData= new FormData()
          formData.append('ActivityID', ActivityID)
          formData.append('image', photo)
              setActivityID(respons.data[0].ActivityID)
              Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/addeventimage', formData, ActivityID)
              .then(res => {               
              console.log(res.data.msg);         
          })
      })     
  })        
  }
```

And this is the code in the server

```
app.post("/addeventimage", upload.single('image'), (req, res, err) => {

  if (!req.file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF)$/)) {
    res.send({ msg: 'Only image files (jpg, jpeg, png) are allowed!' })
  } else {
    const image = req.file.filename;
    const ActivityID= SELECT ActivityID FROM activity WHERE ActivityID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    db.query(
      INSERT INTO activityimages(ActivityID, image) VALUES ("${ActivityID}", "${image}"),
      [ActivityID, image], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          res.send({
            msg: err
          });
        }
        else if (result) {
          res.send({
            data: result,
            msg: 'Your image has been inserted!'
          });
        }

      });
  }
})

app.get("/addevent", (req, res) => {
  db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM activity WHERE ActivityID= LAST_INSERT_ID()",
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  )})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already sending `ActivityID` from the client. You just need to use it.

Remove this line in your `/addeventimage` API:

```
const ActivityID = SELECT ActivityID FROM activity WHERE ActivityID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

and use the value coming from the client:

```
const ActivityID = req.body.ActivityID;
```

**Explanation:**

Error `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` occurs when you try to use `FK` value which does not exist in the parent table. Like you want to use `ActivityID = 10` and it doesn't even exist in `activity` table.

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` function returns the last id inserted by the connection. Since your second API call is a separate call, it may create a new connection to the database where `LAST_INSERT_ID()` output will be `0` and it will throw an error because `ActivityID = 0` will not be found.

Comment: and this is how you get your data stolen by SQL Injection

Comment: It is still the same error

Comment: @Ernesto I know. But I can't fix the entire code. There are so many things. I suppose OP will learn those things on the way.

Comment: @BatoolNassar Check what `req.body.ActivityID` returns on the server?